# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in flutter

Tags: flutter, list

I try to display my images coming from my database but I get error type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'.I tried a lot to find the cause of the problem, but I did not find a solution to it. I am a new flutter developer. I looked at previous posts on the site here as well, but I couldn't solve the problem still.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_immo1/models/items_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_immo1/screens/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_immo1/widgets/house_card.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class SuggestionList extends StatefulWidget {
  SuggestionList(this.title, this.items, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  String? title;
  List<Item> items;
  @override
  State<SuggestionList> createState() => _SuggestionListState();
}

class _SuggestionListState extends State<SuggestionList> {
  List item = [];
  getData() async {
    var url =
        'http://selogerabidjan.global-aeit.com/flutter/logement_concret.php';
    print(url);
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    item = json.decode(response.body);
    print(item);
    return item;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.title!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("See All")),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 12.0,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 340.0,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: item.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                width: 300.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xfcf9f8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (() {}),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 160.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(item[index]['thumb_url']),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 18.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          item[index],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue.shade600,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          item[index]['title'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue.shade600,
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.location_on,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              item[index]['location'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${item[index]['price']}\$/month",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline))
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
Text(
      item[index],
      style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue.shade600,
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
```

`item[index]` is a Map and you have putted it directly in a Text widget, where you are only allowed to put a string. You can put item[index]['title'] instead.

Comment: thank for item[index]['title'] but why i have to update before the images are displayed

Comment: @msi `getData()` is a `Future` method. You have to use `FutureBuilder` instead of  `ListView.builder` to show images without any update of the state.